# Creating a new column with end of each month YMD date given the year&month (dplyr)

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate, zoo

I want to create a new column that shows last day of each month in ymd format given the year&month in the same row. Something like this:

```
month_year    end_month
Jan 2022      31/01/2022
Jan 2022      31/01/2022
Feb 2022     28/02/2022
March 2022    31/03/2022
```

```
library(zoo)
library(tidyverse)

# Print data example with specific columns
dput(df[1:20,c(1,19,23)])
```

output:

```
structure(list(id = 1:20, posted_date = c("2023-03-12 00:00:00", 
"2023-03-13 00:00:00", "2023-03-20 00:00:00", "2023-03-08 00:00:00", 
"2023-03-16 00:00:00", "2023-03-20 00:00:00", "2023-03-09 00:00:00", 
"2023-03-20 00:00:00", "2023-03-13 00:00:00", "2023-03-21 00:00:00", 
"2023-03-07 00:00:00", "2023-03-08 00:00:00", "2023-03-19 00:00:00", 
"2023-03-19 00:00:00", "2023-03-12 00:00:00", "2023-03-12 00:00:00", 
"2023-03-20 00:00:00", "2023-03-20 00:00:00", "2023-03-09 00:00:00", 
"2023-03-12 00:00:00"), month_year = structure(c(2023.16666666667, 
2023.16666666667, 2023.16666666667, 2023.16666666667, 2023.16666666667, 
2023.16666666667, 2023.16666666667, 2023.16666666667, 2023.16666666667, 
2023.16666666667, 2023.16666666667, 2023.16666666667, 2023.16666666667, 
2023.16666666667, 2023.16666666667, 2023.16666666667, 2023.16666666667, 
2023.16666666667, 2023.16666666667, 2023.16666666667), class = "yearmon")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I made a few attempts using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029958/getting-first-and-last-day-of-each-month-in-r) as follows:

```
job_posts %>% 
   group_by(month_year = as.yearmon(Date)) %>%
   summarise(First = floor_date(first(Date), 'month'), 
             Last = ceiling_date(last(Date), 'month')-1)
```

But I keep receiving this error message, but I am confused because the "month_year" in my df is indeed in a yearmon format, not numeric, so I thought the code above should work?
"Error in group_by(., month_year = as.yearmon(Date)) :
Caused by error in `as.numeric()`:
! cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'"

Comment: That error is the one I would expect if you did not actually have a column called `Date` in your data frame, in which case `dplyr` would be trying to perform arithmetic on the _function_ `Date` from base R ('closure' in the error message refers to a function). Indeed, I don't see a column called `Date` in your example data frame.

Comment: Other than the error (which really has nothing to do with real years/months/dates), this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9322923/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6242955/3358272.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three different possibilities for what you're wanting to do:

##### 1. Get the first and last posted_date in each month

```
df |> mutate(first = first(posted_date), last = last(posted_date), .by = month_year)
```

But the rows are not in order, and the first and last row in the data have the same date, so we end up getting the same date for the first and last columns, so I assume this isn't what you want.

##### 2. Get the earliest and latest dates in each month

```
df |> mutate(first = min(posted_date), last = max(posted_date), .by = month_year)
```

But obviously, if the data misses days then we won't get the absolute *last* day in each month.

##### 3.  Get the first and last days of the month of each month_year

```
df |> summarise(first = as.Date(month_year[1]), last = as.Date(month_year[1] + (1/12))-1, .by = month_year)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  month_year first      last      
  <yearmon>  <date>     <date>    
1 Mar 2023   2023-03-01 2023-03-31
```

This final one, I believe, is what you are looking for.

##### Error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double

The issue appears very likely to be, as Allan eloquently stated, that you are *'trying to perform arithmetic on the function [`Date`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Dates.html) from base R*

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2023-01-01"), as.Date("2023-03-31"), by = "days"))

df <- df |>
  mutate(month_year = format(date, "%b %Y")) |>
  mutate(end_month = as.Date(format(date, "%Y-%m-01")) + months(1) - days(1))
```